# Kernel of the Jordan Block

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I was looking at [this problem set](https://pages.uoregon.edu/belias/Classes/607-spring-2016/Exercises.pdf)  by Ben Elias on homological algebra, where he states the following problem :

> Let $x$ be an operator acting on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ by a single Jordan
> block, with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Show that $\ker(x − \lambda I)$ is contained in any nonzero subspace.

Am I missing something or this is wrong? If I take a Jordan basis of $V$, $\{v, (x-\lambda I)v, \dots, (x-\lambda I)^{n-1}v\}$ then clearly the kernel is the one dimensional subspace generated by $v_n=(x-\lambda I)^{n-1}v$. But the nonzero subspace generated by $v$ doesn't contain the kernel.

Comment: What he meant is that that subspace is contained in every *invariant* subspace.

Answer (score 0):

From Mariano Suárez-Álvarez's comment :

I think one proof may be like this. Let $W$ be an invariant subspace. If we choose a Jordan basis $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ where $v_i=(x-\lambda I)^{i-1}v_1$ and $(x-\lambda I)v_n=0$. Then it suffices to show $v_n\in W$. Let $w\in W$ be a nonzero element. Let $w=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iv_i$. Let $j$ be the smallest index for which $a_i\ne 0$. Now notice if $W$ is invariant under $x$ then it is also invariant under $x-\lambda I$. Then consider $(x-\lambda I)^{n-j}(w)=a_jv_n\in W$. So the proof is complete.

Comment: Suppose that W is an invariant subspace. The characteristic polynomial of the restriction of the map to W divides that of the map itself, so \lambda is its (only) root. In particular, the map has an eigenvalue in W. Since the eigenspace if the map has dimension 1, W contains the kernel of x-lambda.